# Bug in the registration system for users - PHP

Tags: php, system

I made this script for the registration of users via a form "POST" which resides in a different page. The script works, manages to capture the data, but when the procedure is completed, the user table I do not get the added user. As if it had never been entered. Even filling in all the fields available, the table remains empty, I would know the reason and stating what is wrong?

```
$dbconnect = new MySQLi(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dbconnect, "????", $name, $surname, $password, $admin);

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, surname, password, admin)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if (mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql)) 
{

?>
<script>
    fadeInPopup();
    popupMessage.text("User add!");
</script>
<?php
}   
else
    {
?>
<script>
    fadeInPopup();
    popupMessage.text("Error: " . mysqli_error($dbconnect););
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
else
    {
?>
<script>
    fadeInPopup();
    var er = '<?php mysqli_error($dbconnect);?>';
    popupMessage.text("Error: "+er);
</script>
```

Comment: I get a blank page, no data will be added in the table